# Why bracket always convert to %28?

Tags: jsp

I am working with export file excel in jsp.
But I have a problem with file name that exist bracket.
It always convert from ( to %28 and ) to %29.

e.g: %28주%29테스트.xlsx

```
String fileName = "(주)테스트.xlsx";
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
workbook.close();
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

Any helps will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting your file name to UTF-8 Charset. In that char set, as you can guess, ( is %28 and ) is %29. And it should not be an issue. It will read it as brackets only. This(as ofcourse) is done by the encode method. You can read about it here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: You are right. it occured because of encode method. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I just decided to do it by using replaceAll method
`.replaceAll("%28","(").replaceAll("%29",")");`